# How to dynamically append thead by Bootstrap Table methods?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, html-table, bootstrap-table

I need to generate all table from json (thead and tbody). When I append header of table in html everething works good, but when I try to append thead dynamical by jquery method `$('table').html`  bootstrap table methods not working and table fill empty elements in tbody.

I try to use `$('table').bootstrapTable('load', 'cols')` or `$('table').bootstrapTable('append', 'cols')`, but this methods working only for tbody.

Comment: See my fiddle where I created a table dynamically by an ajax call with json data: https://jsfiddle.net/bogatyr77/tkg5430m/5/

Comment: Thanks for comment, but with this solution bootstrap table methods are not working. I have a lot of dynamical tables, and looking for solution with bootstrap.